# Translating a database to JSON

Tags: php, json, database

I have a method of creating JSON into an array that looks like this:

```
[{"date":"","name":"","image":"","genre":"","info":"","videocode":""},{...},{...}]
```

I first tried getting the data from a html page (not the database) like this:

```
$arr = array();

$info = linkExtractor($html);
$dates = linkExtractor2($html);
$names = linkExtractor3($html);
$images = linkExtractor4($html);
$genres = linkExtractor5($html);
$videocode = linkExtractor6($html);

for ($i=0; $i<count($images); $i++) {
    $arr[] = array("date" => $dates[$i], "name" => $names[$i], "image" => $images[$i], "genre" => $genres[$i], "info" => $info[$i], "videocode" => $videocode[$i]);
}

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Where each `linkExtractor` looks a bit like this - where it grabs all the text within a class `videocode`.

```
function linkExtractor6($html){ 
    $doc = new DOMDocument(); 
    $last = libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); 
    $doc->loadHTML($html); 
    libxml_use_internal_errors($last); 
    $xp = new DOMXPath($doc); 
    $result = array(); 
    foreach ($xp->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' videocode ')]") as $node) 
        $result[] = trim($node->textContent); // Just push the result here, don't assign it to a key (as that's why you're overwriting)

    // Now return the array, rather than extracting keys from it
    return $result; 
}
```

I now want to do this instead with a database.

So I have tried to replace each `linkExtractor` with this - and obviously the connection:

```
function linkExtractor6($html){ 
    $genre = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT genre
    FROM entries
    ORDER BY date DESC");

    foreach ($genre as $node) 
            $result[] = $node; 
    return $result; 
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: fetch the result set after executing the query

Comment: @jakegould I have connected the database outside the functions? Should I do it multiple times instead? As I am still getting the same error for his answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid redundancy and run a single `SELECT`

```
function create_json_db($con){ 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT date, name, image, genre, info, videocode
                                 FROM entries
                                 ORDER BY date DESC");

    $items= array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       $items[] = $row;
    }

    return $items ; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this. More info in [the official PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php):

```
function linkExtractor6($html){ 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT genre
    FROM entries
    ORDER BY date DESC");

    $items = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       $items[] = $row;
    }

    return $items; 
}
```

Comment: `Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object`

Comment: You need to check if the $result is not FALSE and echo mysql_error(). Also, this API is deprecated. Use PDO instead.

Comment: In that case `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT)` should help to show all the errors and notices.